# Advertising Studio - Use of single audience across multiple campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, advertising-studio

Are there any restrictions on the usage of a single audience? I.e. can I create a single Facebook audience and use that across multiple FB ad campaigns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an audience has been exported to FB Business Manager, you can freely use it in as many campaigns you wish - both as a target audience, as well as your suppression audience.